# Xoom avd - API 11 attach google map

Tags: android

I have download avd "**Xoom (Motorola Mobility Holding INC) - Api Level 11**" for motorola tablet development and configure and integrate the Google map but "**MapActivity**" class required google API class. so i have copy *map.jar* file and add it as External library but not run.i know that there are google API available to perform map Operation but i need to continue with "**Xoom (Motorola Mobility Holding INC) - Api Level 11**" ***not*** google API  so is there any alternet way by which i can integrate google map in this level.